# Laravel Sail starting error related to MySQL on Ububtu 22

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I added Sail to a current Laravel project

```
composer require laravel/sail --dev
php artisan sail:install
```

but when I run `./vendor/bin/sail up` I get MySQL error:

```
:~/work/dashboard$ ./vendor/bin/sail up 
[+] Running 3/3
 ⠿ Network dashboard_sail              Created                                                                                                                                   0.1s
 ⠿ Container dashboard-mysql-1         Created                                                                                                                                   2.8s
 ⠿ Container dashboard-laravel.test-1  Created                                                                                                                                   1.1s
Attaching to dashboard-laravel.test-1, dashboard-mysql-1
dashboard-mysql-1         | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.31-1.2.10-server
dashboard-mysql-1         | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.31-1.2.10-server
dashboard-mysql-1         | 2022-10-17T10:10:38.740784Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
dashboard-mysql-1         | 2022-10-17T10:10:38.741647Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31) starting as process 1
dashboard-mysql-1         | 2022-10-17T10:10:38.750935Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
dashboard-mysql-1         | 2022-10-17T10:10:38.795221Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
dashboard-mysql-1         | 2022-10-17T10:10:39.287522Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
dashboard-mysql-1         | 2022-10-17T10:10:39.287656Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
dashboard-mysql-1         | 2022-10-17T10:10:39.287668Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
dashboard-mysql-1         | 2022-10-17T10:10:39.287971Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
dashboard-laravel.test-1  | 2022-10-17 10:10:41,882 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
dashboard-laravel.test-1  | 2022-10-17 10:10:41,883 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
dashboard-laravel.test-1  | 2022-10-17 10:10:42,885 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 16
dashboard-laravel.test-1  | 
dashboard-laravel.test-1  |    Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
dashboard-laravel.test-1  | 
dashboard-laravel.test-1  |   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = dashboard and table_name = report_errors and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dashboard
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

and when I open `http://localhost` I get `This site can’t be reached`. How to fix this?

[image]

---

[Update]

I run `docker ps -a` and fount 2 containers: onr for sail and the other for MySQL.

```
f20cf9718056   sail-8.1/app           ... dashboard-laravel.test-1
b7007d3a061c   mysql/mysql-server:8.0 ... dashboard-mysql-1
```

I run `docker-compose start` and both containers are running.

```
docker-compose start
Starting mysql        ... done
Starting laravel.test ... done
```

Now I try to run `./vendor/bin/sail up` But I get

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I run `docker ps` but the MySQL container exit

```
f20cf9718056   sail-8.1/app   "start-container"   About an hour ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5173->5173/tcp, :::5173->5173/tcp, 8000/tcp   dashboard-laravel.test-1
```

MySQL Logs

```
docker logs dashboard-mysql-1
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.31-1.2.10-server
[Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.31-1.2.10-server
2022-10-17T14:01:13.615764Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-10-17T14:01:13.616826Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31) starting as process 1
2022-10-17T14:01:13.627454Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-10-17T14:01:13.832319Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-10-17T14:01:14.321686Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-10-17T14:01:14.321863Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-10-17T14:01:14.321881Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-10-17T14:01:14.322186Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.31-1.2.10-server
[Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.31-1.2.10-server
2022-10-17T14:10:37.311446Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-10-17T14:10:37.312494Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31) starting as process 1
2022-10-17T14:10:37.331341Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-10-17T14:10:37.442677Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-10-17T14:10:37.932648Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-10-17T14:10:37.932756Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-10-17T14:10:37.932772Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-10-17T14:10:37.933079Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.31-1.2.10-server
[Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.31-1.2.10-server
2022-10-17T14:10:47.381949Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-10-17T14:10:47.382974Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31) starting as process 1
2022-10-17T14:10:47.389572Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-10-17T14:10:47.411196Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-10-17T14:10:47.901979Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-10-17T14:10:47.902111Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-10-17T14:10:47.902128Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-10-17T14:10:47.902444Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.31-1.2.10-server
[Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.31-1.2.10-server
2022-10-17T15:04:03.773574Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-10-17T15:04:03.774621Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31) starting as process 1
2022-10-17T15:04:03.788273Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-10-17T15:04:03.852948Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2022-10-17T15:04:04.341269Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-10-17T15:04:04.341410Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-10-17T15:04:04.341425Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-10-17T15:04:04.341726Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: try `sudo service docker restart` first to restart docker

Comment: still not solved after restarting docker

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot I'm stuck at `./vendor/bin/sail up` I get `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Answer (score 0):

I did not use Laravel Sail I prefer to make my own docker and docker-compose files so let me get you a bit closer to the error. **Error : Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed** this error can occur due to two reasons.

1. there might be an issue with your DNS settings
2. PHP may not be able to get the network addresses for a given
   host/domain name.
   so you need to make sure the service name in your docker file for MYSQL is used in your Laravel .env file as a DB_HOST. and one more thing Laravel is trying to make a select statement somehow outside of the container so you got the mentioned error above in case you took care of the 2 points I mentioned above.